# docker push error for ibm bluemix watson

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

When following https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-minecraft-watson-trs-4/ and run docker push command.  I received the following error:

> Error response from daemon:  405 Method Not Allowed
>
> ## Method Not Allowed
>
> The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I don't have an answer but I literally laughed out loud when I read this part: "In this section, we introduce a third-party plugin, the Disease plugin, which allows players to bring the terror and fear of infectious diseases to Minecraft town."

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.  I found the answer from online help.  I was not aware I have to do both

```
cf login 
cf ic login
```